# Why my chef recipe to checkout a git repo into a directory built by chef provisioner not working?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

First of all I am new to chef and vagrant.

I already have a working vagrant box based on an open source project at [vdd](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/vdd/tree/). I am trying to add a chef recipe to it that checks out a git repo into a directory prepared by chef provisioner.

So I added a new recipe to in `cookbooks/custom/my_example/default.rb` and added an entry `"recipe[my_example]"` to the `run_list` in `chef/roles/vdd.json`. The recipe is supposed to checkout a git repository to a directory `document_root` which is declared in `config.json` and prepared with `vdd_sites.rb` recipe file. My custom chef recipe I have in `cookbooks/custom/my_example/default.rb` does the follwoing:

```
git "/var/www/drupal7" do
  repository "https://github.com/drupal/drupal.git"
  revision "master"
  checkout_branch 'master'
  action :sync
  user 'vagrant'
  group 'vagrant'
end
```

The relevant config json code is:

```
     "vdd": {
      "sites": {
      "drupal8": {
        "account_name": "root",
        "account_pass": "root",
        "account_mail": "box@example.com",
        "site_name": "Drupal 8",
        "site_mail": "box@example.com",
        "vhost": {
          "document_root": "drupal8",
          "url": "drupal8.dev",
          "alias": ["www.drupal8.dev"]
        }
      },
      "drupal7": {
        "account_name": "root",
        "account_pass": "root",
        "account_mail": "box@example.com",
        "site_name": "Drupal 7",
        "site_mail": "box@example.com",
        "vhost": {
          "document_root": "drupal7/docroot",
          "url": "drupal7.dev",
          "alias": ["www.drupal7.dev"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the code in vdd_sites.rb is:

```
    if node["vdd"]["sites"]
    node["vdd"]["sites"].each do |index, site|
    include_recipe "database::mysql"

    htdocs = defined?(site["vhost"]["document_root"]) ? site["vhost"]["document_root"] : index

    # Avoid potential duplicate slash in docroot path from config.json input.
    if htdocs.start_with?("/")
      htdocs = htdocs[1..-1]
    end

    # Create subidrectores, allow for multiple layers deep.
    htdocs = "var/www/" + htdocs
    htdocs = htdocs.split(%r{\/\s*})
    folder = "/"
    for i in (0..htdocs.length - 1)
      folder = folder + htdocs[i] + "/"
      directory folder do
        owner "vagrant"
        group "vagrant"
        mode "0755"
        action :create
      end
    end

    mysql_connection_info = {
      :host => "localhost",
      :username => "root",
      :password => node["mysql"]["server_root_password"]
    }
    mysql_database index do
      connection mysql_connection_info
      action :create
    end
  end
end
```

However, nothing gets cloned in that directory. if I change the target destination to another directory in my recipe file it works fine. i.e.  `git "/var/www/anotherdir" do ...`

I am not sure what's going on, is it the order of recipe execution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `checkout_branch` line, you don't want that. Yes I know it sounds like you do, but you don't. Check the output from chef-client to make sure your recipe is actually running. You seem to be saying both of those snippets of code are `vdd_sites`?

Comment: I agree but it is not the issue and I did remove it. The problem is in vdd_sites which is building the document root and the directory structure based on sites in config.json. I commented out the for loop `for i in (0..htdocs.length - 1) ..` and the provisioner was able to execute the git checkout properly. If I don't comment it out nothing happens and not even errors are thrown.

Comment: Nothing in the code you cite as `vdd_sites` actually has a git resource. Please include or better label which recipe code is actually running the git resource.

Comment: sorry, the first code snippet is doing the git checkout which is `cookbooks/custom/my_example/default.rb`. it  tries to checkout code into the same directory defined in vdd_site.rb line( `htdocs = "var/www/" + htdocs`) where `htdocs` is defined in `config.json` (`   "document_root": "drupal7",`)

Comment: Check in the chef-client output that your recipe is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is that GIT doesn't much like having files (or directories) in the directories it's creating clones into.  It appears to be as if /var/www/drupal7 at the very least has a subdir /docroot, and maybe a lot more files.

Suggest you create the clone first, then add these files.